# System backup too large for hdd

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, backup, lenovo-laptop

I made a system backup using One Key Recovery (OKR) for my lenovo ideapad, storing it on an external hdd. When I went to recover the backup using OKR it stated the hard drive doesn't have enough space to transfer it back from the external hdd. I literally made this backup of this very drive a day ago.

Short of plugging in a larger drive and retrying, what can I do?

The image size is about 680gb via properties. My hard drive is 1tb with 890 gb listed as the max available.  I'm guessing when it unpacks it, its creating a filesize larger than the original size and larger than the 890gb? Or it thinks it is/might?

Can I go into the backup and remove files to make it smaller? Even emptying my recycle bin would free up alot of space. Can I launch my pc from the external hard drive? What can I do here? I don't have any working knowledge of this recovery stuff, so I'm at a total loss. But I would imagine just removing a couple GB to up to 50 gb would be enough to fix the issue (i can think of specific files that could be removed to freeup this space).

When I made the backup I only had anywhere from 10-25gb of free space on my hdd. I wasn't aware this could be an issue for backups, obviously it is and it won't happen again, but I need a fix and I have no idea what I can do to get the backup to work. I still have hundreds of Gb in space on my external hdd, if that matters.

the backup is a .wsi file

I'm using windows 8.1

[disk management image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LNjb.jpg)

Comment: I suspect the software you attempting to use isn't designed to do anything more then restore files to a single partition.  You very likely would have to create a partition, with enough space, to perform the entire restoration.  I strongly suggest NOT using Lenovo software to perform backups.  One Key Recovery feature set is extemely limited.  The image likely used compression.

Comment: I was able to add 20gb to the main c drive partition, but it still wasn't enough. Do I need to add space to any of the other partitions am I adding to the wrong one? I don't understand this, or is it just my C drive that needs to be bigger? I have another partition called "recovery partition". Infact I have 2, one has 14 gb of space. I don't understand what they do though, do I need to add space to these partitions? Or somehow delete them and add to the C drive? Is there a program that can help me find how much space I need exactly?

Comment: I added a picture of my disk management up above, it won't let me embed

Comment: I'm going to try adding the remaining 5 gb, and transferring the 673gb image over to the hdd. Then I'll restart the computer then I'll try again and restore  the hard drive from the hard drive itself. I don't know if there is any logic in that, but I'll try it cause I'm out of ideas. Next idea is to buy a 1.5-2terabyte drive. Is there no way to run the image from an external hdd? All I need to do is get in and delete some files afterall. Or use a usb or something for extra space for my main hdd?

Comment: I see now I don't need the 15 gb restore partition as long as I create a restore disk usb as that's where windows 8 is stored apparently. So I'll make the usb and add the 15 gb to C and see if that's enough to inflate the C partition to be big enough to enable the backkup....I pray it is.

Comment: You will need to delete the Windows partition, then only then, restore the image, the tool isn’t advanced enough to be able to restore the image over a partition already in use.