# Ways to create more 'total space' on a C:/ Drive, or Trick it into thinking there is. re: external usb or hdd?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, partitioning

[image: disk management pic]

I need to expand the total storage number on the C partition there to as large as possible. What are the ways I can do so? As you can see there is unallocated space in that picture...that can be added to C. The last partition the 14gb one can be dissolved, once I create a windows repair disk anyways, and added to C.

What else can I possibly do to make the C partition "Be" or "trick it into pretending it is" larger than it is?
External USB? External HDD? photo card...anything I can plug in or do that can make that number larger? Any software programs to help clean the drive and really increase the number? All I need is for programs to think space is there.

Why am I asking this? Cause I made a backup using Lenovo's OKR (one key recovery) and it's stating I can't restore it cause there isn't enough space. So I want to trick it into thinking there is, cause I made the backup of the very drive it's saying there's no space on.

Comment: is your hard drive SSD? if yes then it's not recommended to convert unallocated space. otherwise, just right-click it and create a new drive

Comment: a 1tb hdd and 25gb ssd are currently combined as C

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System backup too large for hdd](https://superuser.com/questions/1452553/system-backup-too-large-for-hdd)

Comment: that unallocated space is a failsafe for SSD. you can allocate it if you rly need/want but like mentioned it's not recommended

Comment: its called over-provisioning of SSD. for example:  Samsung Magician performs over-provisioning by actually creating an unallocated partition at the end of the disk. This helps extend the life on the SSD mostly by ensuring that you never fill up the disk up to its full capacity, giving the controller more free cells to play with. Also, 300GB for a 256GB drive would be an overkill. It's safe to assume most 240GB drives have 16GB of over-provisioned space

Comment: For future use, *try one of the free disk imaging apps*, such as Macrium Reflect, which give more flexibility, e.g. imaging one partition, and restoring files from it one-at-a-time or overwriting and restoring the whole partition.